# Upstart script doesn't work on boot - only manually

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, uwsgi, flask

I followed [this](https://github.com/mking/flask-uwsgi) tutorial on setting up Flask with nginx + uwsgi.

I created an upstart script at `/etc/init/flask-uwsgi.conf`:

```
start on [2345]
stop on [06]

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/run/flask-uwsgi
    chown www-data:www-data /var/run/flask-uwsgi
end script

script
    cd /var/flask-uwsgi
    exec uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
end script
```

In order to work, the directory `/var/run/flask-uwsgi` must be created with its owner set to `www-data`.

If I do a hard reboot, this script (and the service) doesn't start automatically.

If I run `service flask-uwsgi start` manually , it works fine.

I tried adding `setuid root` to this script, thinking that you need root privileges to create directories in `/var/run`, but that didn't help.

My syntax appears fine:

```
init-checkconf /etc/init/flask-uwsgi.conf 
File /etc/init/flask-uwsgi.conf: syntax ok
```

And, the log file `/var/log/upstart/flask-uwsgi.log` is empty.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the `stop on` part of the upstart script.

Corrected:

```
start on [2345]
stop on [!2345]

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/run/flask-uwsgi
    chown www-data:www-data /var/run/flask-uwsgi
end script

script
    cd /var/flask-uwsgi
    exec uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
end script
```